# Subset sql column with list of values

Tags: sql, r

I have sql query:

```
select timestamp, COUNT(distinct event)"nb events"
from mytable
group by timestamp
```

and i have a list from R of values:

```
event_list <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

How could i subset my sql query events, so there only be events from event_list? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
select Cast([timestamp] as date) "date", COUNT(distinct event)"nb events" %in% event_list
from yourtable
group by Cast([timestamp] as date)
```

I really need a help

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for conditional aggregation:

```
select Cast([timestamp] as date) "date",
     COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN event IN (...) THEN event END)"nb events"
from yourtable
group by Cast([timestamp] as date)
```